# Should get same result if user searches for same word, different spelling(elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, judgement and judgment are actually the same, but there is a difference in the spelling. But when the query is

```
{
   "query":{
      "match_phrase":{
         "name":{
            "query":"Judgement"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Or

```
{
   "query":{
      "match_phrase":{
         "name":{
            "query":"Judgment"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I should get the same result. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) to achieve your use-case, there are several params to customize the default behaviour of it.

Comment: THANK YOU @Amit- ES enthusiast, I used es synonym analyzer and it solved it

Comment: @sudheesh glad u found the solution, but its costly, anyway i would suggest you to use `fuzzy` thats more applicable for your use-case.